# Vector image - convert JPG to EPS or build EPS from scratch

Tags: conversion, image-processing, vector-graphics

My friend sent a `.jpg` logo to some company and they responded that they do not accept that format and they needed it to be vector version and can't use `.jpg`.

I wonder if converting `.jpg` to `.eps` would be correct step here to send it later to the company.

Or should I not convert it and build it from scratch instead?

How does it work correctly?

Comment: .jpg is a raster graphics, which means it's not scalable to different dimensions like the .eps format.
Your best bet it's to use a raster to vector converter, although all of them have their limitations.
Here is a site that provides that service: https://www.vectorizer.io/, but you might find other free services.
inkscape can also convert raster to vector (Path->Trace Bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

As George have mentioned, you can user online services like

http://image.online-convert.com/

http://vectorizer.io

https://changefile.org/convert-jpg-to-eps

Answer (score 0):

The reason raster formats are unsuitable for some applications is that they don't scale. A JPEG file is just a collection of pixels; if you want to blow it up on a large banner like one you can hang on the outside wall of a building, each pixel will be bigger than your hand.  Something which looks like a circle at the original scale will look like increasingly sloping stairs because you start seeing the individual pixels when you blow it up enough.

Vector graphics, on the other hand, consist of drawing instructions which can be rendered exactly at any scale. A vector file consists of drawing instructions, like "draw a circle at this point with radius *r*" which can be scaled down up or down to suit the medium -- so if *r* is 25mm in the original drawing, you can scale it up to 25m or even 25km and still get a very detailed and crisp circle.

What ultimately makes sense depends on the use case, and the drawing. If it *inherently* displays something like a human face, or a heat map, or pixels which are *supposed* to look jaggy, vectorizing it won't really improve it (though you want to make sure the JPEG has enough resolution to look good at the scale you plan to use it).  But if it's a typical logo, definitely vectorize it. Whether that can be done automatically or requires manual work depends on your ambition level and the complexity of the input picture. A simple logo with just a few colors can probably be done automatically with very good quality; a complex one will almost certainly require manual tweaks, or be redone in a vector drawing program.

(If the artwork was competently done, chances are it *was* originally created in a vector drawing program, and was delivered as a JPEG rendering by mistake, perhaps because of a human communications problem. Then of course just have the artist make it available in a better format.)